# Can a differential equation be applied to aperiodic data?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, data-analysis

I need to know if it’s appropriate to simply apply differential operators to variables from some dataset to form a differential equation and then solving. Or does it require additional steps or a different methodology?

For example, let’s say I have a weather dataset with the following variables:

1. Longitude: x
2. Latitude: y
3. Geopotential Height: z
4. Divergence: $d = d(x,y,z)$

The data when plotted looks something like [this with divergence contoured in yellow](https://www.spc.noaa.gov/obswx/maps/300_220813_12.gif). Just ignore the wind barbs and streamlines.

The differential equation for velocity potential, $\chi = \chi(x,y,z)$ is $\frac{\partial^2{\chi}}{\partial{x}^2} + \frac{\partial^2{\chi}}{\partial{y}^2}=d(x,y,z) $

Can I simply plug in the divergence for the right-hand-side and solve for the the value $\chi$?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking whether you can reproduce the velocity data as gradient of $\chi$. The answer is probably no, for two reasons.

1. Without some boundary conditions $\chi$ is not unique; you can add any harmonic function to it, such as $x^2-y^2$.
2. Even if you deal with item 1, you get a gradient velocity field, while the real field is not really a gradient. Could be a reasonable approximation, or not.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (I had a major surgery a while back), but could you clarify what is meant by "add any harmonic function to it"? Specifically the "add" part. Is there a name for the methodology you're employing in step 1 or perhaps some literature which supports it, I would highly appreciative for it. And I should have clarified that we have Dirichlet Boundary Conditions such that values below a certain order of magnitude we approximate the velocity potential there to be 0. It's similar to the electrostatic potential problem where at a certain distance from the field, it's set to 0.

Comment: Ok with Dirichlet BC, solution to your Poisson equation $\Delta\chi=d$ is unique, assuming that you use any reasonable smoothing of the data $d$. The "add" remark doesn't apply now, but it is only the fact that the Laplace operator is linear, so that $\Delta(\chi+h)=\Delta\chi+\Delta h=d+0$. that doesn't apply now because with Dirichlet BC there is no harmonic $h$ other than 0. Any book on pde will discuss these things. Also on item 2, I see in the figure that the streamline through the 4 corners seems to be a closed loop. That is not possible in a gradient field.

Comment: Ah! Well alright then! Glad to know that no additional work is needed there. As for your remark on the plot, I'm assuming you're talking about the single streamline that goes over the 4 corners states of CO, NM, AZ, and UT and then wraps around clockwise through the Great Plains and reconnects, correct? That might be due to computer modeling drawing everything which we know in Meteorology can often get things wrong. The streamlines are supposed to be snapshot of the wind field and we have a deep, hot anticyclonic contiguous airmass that seasonally sits over the 4 corners every summer.